# How to save records to custom object?

Tags: apex, visualforce

can you help me save multiple records from visualforce page into a custom object. I have used wrapper please see the code below.

### Controller

```
    public with sharing class PTCSchedulerCX{
        public set<ID> teachers = new set<ID>();
        public set<ID> selectedTId = new set <ID>();
        public set<String> checkSchedTeaID = new set<String>(); 
        public set<string> qryTime= new set<string>();
        public string selectedSId                   {get;set;}
        public string teacherSet                    {get;set;}
        public List<WrapperClass> wrapTS            {get;set;}
        public List<schedule__c> wrapTeaSched       {get;set;}
        public List<String> saveItems               {get;set;}
        public SET<Id> myTea                        {get;set;}


        String day = '';
        public String getDay(){
            Datetime dt = System.now();
            day = dt.format('EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY');
            return day;
        }   

//GET STUDENTS//
        public List<selectOption> getsNames(){
            List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>(); 
            options.add(new selectOption('--None--', '--Select Student--'));
            for(Parent__c p : [Select Id, Name, First_Name__c, (Select Id, First_Name__c, Name from Students__r) 
                               from Parent__c WHERE Name = 'Delgado']){
                                   for(Student__c stud : p.Students__r){
                                       selectedSId = stud.Id;    
                                       options.add(new selectOption(stud.Id, stud.First_Name__c + ' ' + stud.Name));
                                   }
                               }
            return options;    
        }

//MAIN CONSTRUCTOR//      

        public PTCSchedulerCX(){
                    selectedSId = '--None--';
                    selectedTId = new SET<ID>();
                    wrapTS = new List<WrapperClass>();
                    myTea = new SET<Id>();
                    for(Schedule__c p : [Select Id, Name, Subject__c, Teacher__c, Time__c 
                        from Schedule__c]){
                            wrapTS.add(new WrapperClass(p));
                    }
                    for(teacher__c t : [select id, name, first_name__c, teacher_set__c, room_assignment__c 
                        from teacher__c  where Id = : myTea]){
                            wrapTS.add(new WrapperClass(t));
                    }     
                }
//WRAPPER CLASS//        
                public class WrapperClass{
                    public Teacher__c t1                         {get;set;}
                    public Schedule__c p1                        {get;set;}
                    public student__c s1                         {get;set;}
                    public String strCheck                       {get;set;}
                    public string selectedTime                   {get;set;}

                    public WrapperClass(teacher__c myTea){     
                        t1 = myTea;
                    }

                    public WrapperClass(Schedule__c p){
                        p1 = p;
                    }
                    public WrapperClass(student__c s){
                        s1 = s;
                    }
                }
//GET TEACHERS//      
                public void fetchTeacherInfo(){
                    myTea.clear();
                    wrapTS.clear();
                    wrapTS = new List<WrapperClass>();

                        for (student__c stud : [Select Id, name, first_name__c, parent__c, teacher_set__c 
                            from student__c WHERE Id = : selectedSId]){   
                                teacherSet = stud.teacher_set__c;
                        }
                        for (teacher__c myTeacher : [Select Id, name, first_name__c, teacher_set__c, middle_name__c 
                            from teacher__c WHERE teacher_set__c = : teacherSet]){                  
                                myTea.add(myTeacher.id);
                        }
                        for(teacher__c t : [select id, name, first_name__c, teacher_set__c,Subject__c , room_assignment__c 
                            from teacher__c  where Id = : myTea]){
                               wrapTS.add(new WrapperClass(t));
                        }    
                }

//CHECK TEACHER SCHEDULE//  
                public void checkTeacherSched(){

                    checkSchedTeaId.clear();
                    wrapTeaSched = new list<schedule__c>();

                        for(WrapperClass objsched: wrapTS){
                            checkSchedTeaID.add(objsched.selectedTime);   

                       }
                        for(schedule__c objsched1 : [Select id, name, teacher__c, time__c, student__c, parent__c, teacher_cname__c 
                            from schedule__c WHERE teacher__c =: myTea ]){
                                qryTime.add(objsched1.time__c);
                               // system.assertequals(qryTime+ '','test');
                        }

                        for(WrapperClass objsched: wrapTS){
                            if(qryTime.contains(objsched.selectedTime)){
                                objsched.strCheck ='Time is no longer available';
                            }
                            else{
                                objsched.strCheck = 'AVAILABLE';
                            }
                        }


                }

//SAVING RECORD//
                Public void save(){

                }
            }
```

### VFP

```
<apex:page controller="PTCSchedulerCX"  sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>PTC Scheduler</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>

        <body>
            <apex:form id="formid">
                <div class="container">
                    <apex:pageBlock >

                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </div> 
            </apex:form>

            <apex:form >
                <div class="container">
                    <apex:pageBlock >
                        <div>         
                            <apex:outputLabel style="margin-left: 55px;">DELGADO, PAULO</apex:outputLabel>
                            <apex:outputLabel style="float: right; margin-right: 100px;" value="{!day}" ></apex:outputLabel>
                        </div>       
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </div>
            </apex:form>

            <apex:form >
                <div class="container">
                    <apex:pageBlock id="chooseStudentPageBlock" >            
                        <div>    
                            <apex:outputText value="{!selectedSId}" style="display:none;"></apex:outputText>
                            <apex:outputLabel style="margin-left: 55px;">Select Student:</apex:outputLabel>
                            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedSId}" size="1" style="margin-left: 5px;"  >             
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!sNames}"></apex:selectOptions>
                                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!fetchTeacherInfo}" reRender="teacherBlock"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </div>                 
                    </apex:pageBlock>            
                </div> 

                <div class="container">                
                    <apex:pageBlock id="teacherPageBlock">    
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 45px;"> 
                            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!WrapTS}" var="item" id="teacherBlock">

                                <apex:column headerValue="Teacher" value="{!item.t1.First_Name__c} {!item.t1.Name}"/>
                                  <apex:param id="teacherid" name="teacherId" value="{!item.t1.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedTea}"/> 
                                <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!item.t1.Subject__c}"/>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Room" value="{!item.t1.Room_Assignment__c}"/>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Time">
                                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!item.selectedTime}">
                                     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!checkTeacherSched}" reRender="statusCol"/>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue=""></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="9:00AM - 10:00AM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="10:00AM - 11:00AM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="11:00AM - 12:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="12:00PM - 1:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="1:00PM - 2:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="2:00PM - 3:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="3:00PM - 4:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="4:00PM - 5:00PM"></apex:selectOption>
                                    <!--    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!checkTeacherSched}" reRender="teacherBlock"/> -->
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Status" id="statusCol">
                                  <!-- <apex:outputText value="{!item.strCheck}">  </apex:outputText> -->
                                    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.cross)}" width="20" height="20"
                                        rendered="{!IF(item.strCheck ='Time is no longer available',true,false)}"/>
                                    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.check)}" width="20" height="20"
                                        rendered="{!IF(item.strCheck ='AVAILABLE',true,false)}"/> 
                                </apex:column>

                            </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        </div>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </div>
            </apex:form>            

            <apex:form >         
                <div class="container" align="right"> 
                    <apex:pageBlock >    
                        <div style="margin-right: 50px;">       
                            <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                         <!--   <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Proceed"/> -->
                        </div>
                    </apex:pageBlock>       
                </div>
            </apex:form>         
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        </body> 

    </html>     
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit on how the accepted answer doesn't quite answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, you've accepted it...this setup doesn't exactly prompt new users to try to answer your question.

Comment: This has got to be the weirdest bounty offer ever on SFSE.

Answer (score 2):

So in your save method iterate over wrapper list and get all the records

And store into new list so you can update those records outside of for loop

Like

```
List<Teacher__c> lstTeacher = new List<Teacher__c>();
List<Schedule__c > lstSchedule = new List<Schedule__c >();
List<student__c > lststudent = new List<student__c >();

for(WrapperClass objsched: wrapTS){

lstTeacher.add(objsched.t1);
lstSchedule.add(objsched.p1);
lststudent.add(objsched.s1);                            
}

update lstTeacher;
update lstSchedule;
update lststudent;
```

Not sure which two objects you want to update but for now I have added all three 
Based on your requirement you can modify.

Comment: this is for updating already existing records am i right?

Comment: @gelay Yes.. This will update existing records.

Comment: what if i just want to insert the data

Comment: @gelay then you need to use `Insert` DML on new List of SOBJECT that will contain any new records like student, teacher etc.